# How to integrate Appium to test SMS receving in a web app test framework built with WebdriverIO JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, appium, webdriver-io

current structure of web application testing framework built with webdriverIO JS. (exmple of testing signup)

```
├── Tests
│   ├──signup.spec.js
├── Pages
│   ├── SignUp.js
├── wdio.conf.js
```

sigup.spec.js where to test Signup functionality

```
describe('Account Registration', () => {
  it('should Enter valid phone number to create a new Account ', () => {
    SignUpPage.submitValidCredentials(validphoneumber);
   // here need to open phone and check sms received using appium
  // now put the SMS otp number in the webapp
     expect(this.AlertMessage.getText()).toContain('you have registered successfully');
  });
});
```

my wdio.conf.js contains cofguration for web app automation using chrome driver so how to add Appium configuration to that also ?
PS : this has to be added to test that our service is sending SMS properlly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appium allows to access and open a preinstalled native app instead of running an application using APK, here is the full script
[Android Launch already installed App](https://discuss.appium.io/t/android-launch-already-installed-app/5020/8), along with wdio configuration of Appium.
Also a very helpfull [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXaxOL-6gPA&t=1076s) that answer my question in details.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than thinking of Appium, Easy way is to integrate some SMS supporting capability. Check 'Mailinator' using which you can achieve your requirement.

Mailinator allows to automatically test SMS and Email workflows like 2FA verifications, sign-ups, and password resets.

More info: [Mailinator details](https://www.mailinator.com/)

Comment: Thanls for your answer but it has to be with Appium JS

Comment: Mailinator has exposed rest api to read the SMS.. so you can integrate mailinator using JS directly though any JS based rest client library